# Is it possible that update of android app could delete internal storage data?

Tags: android, android-internal-storage, android-update-app

some people has problem, that if they update app it delete their saved data. The app is saving data into internal data storage. Is it possible? (for example some old version of android could do it? or some another posibility?)

Comment: was it on the database? did you upgrade the database in your update?

Comment: no I didnt make any change about work with data

Comment: Not unless there's a bug in some device.  Updates should keep your data.

Comment: What kind of bug could it be?

Comment: This question is too broad and calls for speculation, hence it does not fit on Stackoverflow.   Any app can delete its own data, how or why it would do that is a question for the developer.